# Выборка по дню недели

Tags: sql

Есть таблица со столбцами соответствующими дню недели (`Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su`) типа `time(7)`. Если в этот день есть занятие, то будет стоять время.

Надо выбрать все занятия сегодня.
Не могу сообразить, как составить запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
select *
  from tableX
 where ELT(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()),Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa) is not null
```

`DAYOFWEEK(NOW()` возвращает номер дня недели, 1-воскресенье, 2-понедельник и т.п. `ELT()` выдает один из своих параметров по номеру соответствующий первому параметру, т.е. в зависимости от дня недели он выдаст один из столбцов, который мы и проверяем на заполненность.

Вообще структура базы не особо удачна, стоило бы хранить больше записей с указанием подходящих дней недели, например битовой маской и одной колонкой с временем. Битовая маска это число представленное требуемыми битами, например для воскресенья (1й день недели) и пятницы(6й) это число 2^1+2^6=66 и проверяем логическими операциями типа `field & (1 << DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) != 0`. Или делаем текстовое поле в котором каждый день недели кодируем одной буквой или цифрой и ищем like, например понедельник и пятница обозначаем 'MF'.

Comment: Типа если занятие в понедельник и пятницу, то хранить "1000100" и время?

Comment: `ELT` для Transact-SQL можно заменить на `CHOOSE`

Comment: А как сделать так, что-бы только этот столбец выводился ?

Comment: Думаю так же choose/elt.

Answer (score 1):

В Oracle, например, можно сделать так:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE time = substr(to_char(sysdate, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH'), 0, 2)
```

где `time` - ваш столбец с днем недели,`'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH'` возвращает день недели в английском варианте (возвращает 3 буквы дня недели, поэтому берем подстроку из первых двух букв).

Comment: Судя по всему у ТС в таблице 7 столбцов по одному для каждого дня недели